# Lint & Prettier repo without mass merge conflicts

Tags: javascript, github, merge, eslint, prettier

I've recently updated our code base to ES6. Following this I am improving the linter rules, and working to have a set standard in the code base. My plan was to commit an initial branch which just had the eslint and prettier setup in them. Then directly following commit another branch with eslint --fix and prettier run on it. (We are okay that this would end up screwing up a lot of git blame). One of the major changes in this transition is moving from 4 spaces (and tabs in many places) to 2 spaces project wide.

The plan was that any existing branches would then be able to pull the commit that had the prettier tools in it. They could run prettier/eslint on their in progress feature and then should be able to merge.

The problem I am running into is that after doing this in a test run, every single change that existed in the feature branch comes up as a merge conflict. Most of the time the merge conflict is with nothing at all.

This problem only affects branches that exist and are currently being worked on, it does not affect any branches that would be created after the linting has been committed.

I've tried doing a diff / merge with different algorithms. The diff looks fine, but then the merge still comes up with conflicts.

Does anyone have experience in converting their existing project over to a new indentation like this or doing any sort of prettier / eslint --fix?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? We are experiencing the same issues on our codebase. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I have people on my team do after upgrading Prettier, changing its config, adding it for the first time, etc to prevent merge conflict headaches on their branch:

```
git fetch origin master:master

# rebase against stage, choosing your code in case of a conflict, and then running the new prettier after each commit
git rebase -i master -X theirs \
   --exec 'yarn && $(npm bin)/prettier --write $(git diff --name-only head^ | xargs) && git commit -a --amend --no-edit'
```

You could take a similar approach with `lint-staged`, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this while looking for an answer to the same question. I thought to share my planned approach:

Work with the team to converge all branches at the same time back to master that can be merged. Once all branches are merged (or accepted to be pruned), execute the linting. Everyone pulls the linted version and is able to diverge again into their own branches.

I'd love for there be a way to record in-line deltas with Git, but until then we'll have to be a bit creative.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to dealing with this kind of scenario is to use a merge tool that applies the formatting fixes to the files before merging, for example:

https://github.com/emilio/clang-format-merge

With this approach, people can rebase and merge old branches onto the latest formatting updated main branch and conflicts that were caused by formatting alone will not occur.